# I have uploaded an app for iTunes, the build is there but the details is not visible.

Tags: app-store-connect

I have uploaded an app for iTunes, the build is there but the details (whether rejected, under review or available for testing) is not visible. This is unlike my previous apps which show said details.

Comment: Update, the iTunes helpdesk sent me an email. It said my submission was lacking some assets. It does not say what assets. But I made sure all assets were the same from the previous builds I had.

Comment: do you submit that build for review ? until you select that build for test or review build status will be empty.

Comment: Yes. I have submitted it for review already. Just like how I uploaded and submitted my previous apps. That is why I was really irked why this happens. It made me lose some deadlines.